# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel. How to prevent slid event from finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I try to prevent carousel slide from execution on some conditions with little effect.

Here is my code:

```
$('#questionsSlider').on('slide', '', function(e) {
            if( !testGroupCompletion($('.questionGroup.active').attr('groupno')))
                if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        });
```

but when function returns false, not only carousel stands still but stops working at all. Anyone know what I should return to prevent sliding?

Comment: Any url or fiffle where we can see?

Comment: I'll try to create fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

this line may help you..

again load the carousel

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
      $(this).carousel('pause') 
})
```

Comment: Nope, already tried it. It prevents from sliding after some interval. It don't prevent from slide.